# The `open` function does not create the file at the mentioned path

Tags: python

i got this code:

```
data = os.path.join(os.getenv("APPDATA"), "acctoolspremiumaccess.txt")

open(f"{data}", 'w').close()
```

it should create the file in the `appdata` folder, but it creates it in the same folder as the `py` file's folder

(Sorry if my english is bad, its not my main language (:)

Comment: What is the value of `data`? What does `os.getenv("APPDATA")` return? These are both critical information to understand what your code is doing.

Comment: `print(repr(os.getenv("APPDATA"))` will show empty strings too.

Comment: Did you print `data`? What output did you get? And`f"{data}"` is somehow strange since the result will be just `data`.

Comment: and by the way there is no need to use f-string for `data`

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. Also, why do you think `open()` is the problem and not your environment?

Comment: Print the value of `data`, so you can see where the fire is being created.

Comment: And what is `os.getcwd()`? If APPDATA is the empty string, then you'll write to current working directory, not the .py file's directory. Of course, those can be the same if you cd'd into the .py file directory and ran the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the `APPDATA` environment variable doesn't contain a full path or it's empty. If the path is not a full path or it's empty then the path will be started where you call your script from.

**Test code:**

```
import os

full_path = "/home/user"  # Full path -> /home/user/<your_file>
not_full_path = "admin"  # NOT full path -> <your_current_location>/admin/<your_file>
empty_path = ""  # Empty path -> <your_current_location>/<your_file>

print(f"I am here: {os.getcwd()}")  # It returns your current location

data_full_path = os.path.join(full_path, "acctoolspremiumaccess.txt")
data_not_full_path = os.path.join(not_full_path, "acctoolspremiumaccess.txt")
data_empty_path = os.path.join(empty_path, "acctoolspremiumaccess.txt")

print(data_full_path)
print(data_not_full_path)
print(data_empty_path)

open(f"{data_full_path}", 'w').close()
open(f"{data_not_full_path}", 'w').close()
open(f"{data_empty_path}", 'w').close()
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
I am here: /home/user/working_dir/tools
/home/user/acctoolspremiumaccess.txt
admin/acctoolspremiumaccess.txt
acctoolspremiumaccess.txt
```

**Generated files checking:**

```
>>> ll /home/user/acctoolspremiumaccess.txt 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 Sep 22 19:24 /home/user/acctoolspremiumaccess.txt

>>> ll /home/user/working_dir/tools/admin/acctoolspremiumaccess.txt 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 Sep 22 19:24 /home/user/working_dir/tools/admin/acctoolspremiumaccess.txt

>>> ll /home/user/working_dir/tools/acctoolspremiumaccess.txt 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 Sep 22 19:24 /home/user/working_dir/tools/acctoolspremiumaccess.txt
```

Or you can print the full paths of where the file will be generated with the `os.path.abspath()`.

**In case of my example:**

```
print(os.path.abspath(data_full_path))
print(os.path.abspath(data_not_full_path))
print(os.path.abspath(data_empty_path))
```

**Output:**

```
/home/user/acctoolspremiumaccess.txt
/home/user/working_dir/tools/admin/acctoolspremiumaccess.txt
/home/user/working_dir/tools/acctoolspremiumaccess.txt
```

I think you can debug your code based on my answer.